# How to set a number of parallel jobs for make in Cmake QtCreator project?

Tags: makefile, cmake, qt-creator

My project is managed by CMake and I use QtCreator as a main IDE.
I want to make QtCreator run `make -j number_here` command when it launches a build task to speed it up, but I am unable to find a corresponding configuration in QtCreator's project settings UI. I became somewhat lost in all it's settings.

Should I modify `CMakeLists.txt` file somehow or is it configurable from the QtCreator's UI?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can configure this in Qt Creator:

1. Go to: `left panel`/`Projects`/`Build Settings`.
   Note: On the left `Build & Run`, select the `build` of your targeted "Kit" if you have several.
2. `Build Steps` (below CMake options), click `Details`.
3. In `Tools arguments:` add `-jnumber_here`.
4. Profit!

ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-build-j